# phpMyAdmin is showing error when viewing a table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When clicking browse to view a table I get these error messages and I have no idea why.

I recently switched my server from HostGator to a google cloud compute engine. Both use MySQL and PHP 7.3.

```
Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#613
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

./libraries/sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2062: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'levelcod_guidedata',
string 'Pokemon',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `Pokemon`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'levelcod_guidedata',
string 'Pokemon',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `Pokemon`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to this reported bug
 https://medium.com/@chaloemphonthipkasorn/fix-bug-phpmyadmin-sql-lib-php-php7-2-ubuntu-16-04-836049630a40